# Python: Key error after using get()

Tags: python, keyerror

I have a code here which counts the number of similar second words in a line starting with 'From ', finds which one occurs the max number of times and prints the word along with its frequency.

On the line using the get method, i get a Key Error:(insert second word here). This key error occurs for the first sentence itself and the loop doesn't iterate through. I have absolutely no clue why this is happening.

```
name = raw_input("Enter file:")
fh = open(name)
d=dict()
max=0
key=''
for line in fh:
    line=line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith('From '):
        x=line.split()
        d[x[1]] = d.get(d[x[1]],0) + 1
for z in d:
    if d[z]>max:
        max=d[z]
        key = z
print key, max
```

Thank You.

Comment: The error is from `d[x[1]]` in the get call

Comment: The code would be easier to read (and I suspect the error would jump out at you) if you wrote something like `from_, name, rest = line.split(None, 2)` instead of using `x` as a raw tuple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
d[x[1]] = d.get(d[x[1]],0) + 1
```

This line doesn't look right to me. If you're trying to increment `d[x[1]]`, initialilzing it to zero if it doesn't yet exist, do:

```
d[x[1]] = d.get(x[1],0) + 1
```

... Or just use a `defaultdict` or `Counter`, which perform initialization by default and you can just do `d[x[1]] += 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Use defaultdict() inplace of dict().

Comment: this does not really answer the question (as it stands at least), thats not to say its wrong ... maybe it should be a comment or you should provide an example demonstrating how to use defaultdict instead ...

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d.get(d['a'], 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'a'
```

You get a `KeyError` because 'a' is not in d.

So in your case, in the KeyError happens when you are creating the key for get to seek, not in the call to get itself (which should be impossible).